# VB.NET - Combine TakeWhile and SkipWhile to get both partitions

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, partitioning

Is there a way to combine a `TakeWhile` and `SkipWhile` on the same list using the same predicate to get both partitions, or would that be premature optimization? Would this be done automatically behind the scenes?

**Note that the list is sorted by `Property`**

Here's how I would get both halves of the partition without optimization:

```
Dim partA = list.TakeWhile(Function(e) e.Property = True)
Dim partB = list.SkipWhile(Function(e) e.Property = True)
```

I could also do this in one shot with an `IEnumerator`, but is there any point if I won't have more than several hundred items in the collection?

EDIT: So would this be better since it only iterates through the collection once?

```
Dim partA As List(Of MyType)
Dim partB As List(Of MyType)
Dim iter = list.GetEnumerator()
While iter.MoveNext()
    If iter.Current.Property = True Then
        partA.Add(iter.Current)
    Else
        partB.Add(iter.Current)
    End If
End While
```

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this with linq, you'd probably need to do a for loop yourself. That having been said unless evaluating your predicate is a very expensive operation it is probably premature optimisation and the readability of what you have now will probably outweigh performance gains and a probably less readable block of code.

Comment: I think the readability of this is not that good actually. A helper method to split a list into two would be nicer.

Comment: @Chris My predicate is as simple as a single property-to-string comparison.

Comment: Is only the first switch from e.Property = True to e.Property = False of interest, or you just interested in partitioning by e.Property in general?

Comment: @JerryFederspiel I am now going to be partitioning by the property in general, so I'll see how well `ToLookup` works. I wish I'd known about this function earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit is not equivalent to the first two lines of code in your question, unless all Trues occur before all Falses.  If you want a built-in way to do what you are doing in your edit, you can do

```
Dim itemsByProperty = list.ToLookup(Function(e) e.Property)
```

Now the equivalent of `partA` is `itemsByProperty(True)`, and `partB`'s equivalent is `itemsByProperty(False)`.

Comment: I clarified that in my question just now. The list is sorted beforehand.

Comment: So do you know if this has similar performance to what I did in the edit, assuming that after I use `ToLookup`, I'll need to do `partA.AddRange(itemsByProperty(True))` and the same with `partB` (or `Concat()`)? (I didn't show it in my question, but I need to add my results into *another* already existing collection)

Comment: I haven't measured it, but it is very likely that my solution is slower than yours by a constant factor.

The AddRange at the end will have essentially the same performance penalty for both.

If performance is essential, you *could* try directly adding the items to the ultimate collection instead of (adding to partA, then using AddRange).  The catch there is that AddRange may be able to avoid resizing the backing array too much because it ultimately knows how many elements it's going to add, so that approach might not actually help.  It may be worth it to try both ways and measure.

Comment: I would also guess that Concat will be *much worse* than AddRange.  AddRange is directly implemented on List and could work intelligently with the backing array; Concat is an extension method that has to work with any old IEnumerable.